# Relation between a curve and an ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

[image]

(apologies for the chosen nomenclature, as there's probably a much better term to illustrate that concept)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

Let $t_1$ be the infimum of $\{ t>t_0:\;\alpha(t)=u(t)\}$, then

$$
\alpha'(t_1)>f(t,\alpha(t_1))=f(t,u(t_1))=u'(t_1)
$$
but
$$
\alpha'(t_1)=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0^-}\frac{\alpha(t_1+h)-\alpha(t_1)}{h} \cdots
$$